# How to adjust ggplot secondary y-axis to change position of bar plot layer of mixed plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a mixed plot (2 lines and 1 bar plot) using GGPlot.  The bars represent the percent difference between the two lines on the plot.  It looks good except for the positioning of the bars relative to the lines.  I would like to be able to adjust the secondary y-axis (i.e. the bar plot axis) to range from -50 to 50 (i.e. centre at 0) without affecting the primary y-axis, which I would like to have start at 0.  Does anyone know a way to do this? The current code that I am working on and the resulting plot look like this:

```
year<-c(1995:2018)
value1<-c(1116.87,3030.85,2676.40,3809.81,2459.74,2666.61,2678.28,3303.45,1839.21,3567.79,4529.22,5838.21,7762.13,8079.70,9615.55,9645.06,8297.23,8974.69,12757.06,13052.86,13670.74,17598.57,17190.01,20192.92)
value2<-c(998.22,3551.52,2421.50,3647.22,2085.44,2558.46,2863.98,3332.18,1606.40,3445.12,4893.11,5486.48,7242.37,7356.78,8810.64,7787.83,7507.25,8442.26,10347.11,11002.82,8783.90,15604.60,14648.09,15368.58)
df1<-data.frame(year,value1,value2)
df1$diff<-((df1$value1-df1$value2)/df1$value1)*100

library(ggplot2)

plot1<-ggplot(df1, aes(x = year)) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=year, y = (diff*200), fill="percent diff"), stat="identity") +
  geom_line(aes(y=value1,color="A")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=value2, color="B")) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./200, name = "percent diff")) +
  ylab("Value") +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),legend.title = element_blank(), legend.spacing.y = unit(-0.1, "cm")) +
  scale_color_manual(" ",values=c("A"="#619CFF", "B"="#F8766D", "percent diff"=NA)) +
  scale_fill_manual(" ",values=c("percent diff"="gray")) 

plot1
```

[image]

To be clear, the below plot (done in Excel) is what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]